# SAP Cloud SDK on premise connection is aborted because SYTEM_USER not found?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to use SAP Cloud SDK to connect my app in CF with on-premise S/4. Via Destinations&Cloud Connecttor.

When I deployed the app, it crashes with the following exception (longer version at end):

> Error creating bean with name 'xxx' defined in file
> [/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/classes/de/zzz/xxx/handlers/xyzHandler.class]:
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [de.zzz.xxx.handlers.xyzHandler]: Constructor threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SYSTEM_USER

Code of my handler:

```
private final HttpDestination httpDestination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("s4_techuser").asHttp()
            .decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
```

Besides that, my handler ist more or less empty. I'm just trying to call the bp api:

```
final BusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();
this.businessPartner = service.getBusinessPartnerByKey(businessPartnerId).executeRequest(this.httpDestination);
```

which he never executes because he breaks off beforehand

The destination is (to my knowledge) used by others. However, in nodejs and not java, otherwise I would peek there. Nobody defines a field "SYSTEM_USER". Can one of you give me a hint where this comes from?

My application.yaml

```
spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: cloud
cds:
  remote.services:
    '[API_BUSINESS_PARTNER]':
      destination:
        type: "odata-v2"
        name: "s4_techuser"
        suffix: "/sap/opu/odata/sap"
```

There is nothing special in the mta.yaml. Only my one module which requests the xsuaa, destination and connectivity services. They are all created and the binding to the app exists as well. I'm using the sap_machine and jdk 17 and sdk version 4.8.0.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Log:

> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
> ~[app/:na] 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused
> by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [de.zzz.xxx.handlers.xyzHandler]: Constructor threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SYSTEM_USER
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25] 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000
> [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25] 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000
> [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25] 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000
> [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ... 25 common frames omitted
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by:
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SYSTEM_USER 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000
> [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.isAuthenticationTypeRequiringUserTokenExchange(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:492)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.doesDestinationConfigurationRequireUserTokenExchange(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:239)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByTenant(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:219)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByRetrievalStrategy(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:186)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.loadAndParseDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:138)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.GetOrComputeSingleDestinationCommand.lambda$prepareCommand$0(GetOrComputeSingleDestinationCommand.java:69)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75) ~[vavr-0.10.4.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> io.vavr.control.Try.ofSupplier(Try.java:92) ~[vavr-0.10.4.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.GetOrComputeSingleDestinationCommand.execute(GetOrComputeSingleDestinationCommand.java:147)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> io.vavr.control.Try.flatMapTry(Try.java:490) ~[vavr-0.10.4.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> io.vavr.control.Try.flatMap(Try.java:472) ~[vavr-0.10.4.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader$Cache.getOrComputeDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:972)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader$Cache.access$000(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:538)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:117)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf-4.8.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoaderChain.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoaderChain.java:82)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-4.5.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoader.java:37)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-4.5.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:142)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-4.5.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.getDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:120)
> ~[cloudplatform-connectivity-4.5.0.jar:na]
> 2023-03-05T23:18:26.951+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at
> de.zzz.xxx.handlers.xyzHandler.(xyzHandler.java:38)
> ~[classes/:na]

Handler.class

```
@Component
@ServiceName(xyzService_.CDS_NAME)
public class xyzHandler implements EventHandler {
    private final HttpDestination httpDestination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("s4_techuser").asHttp()
            .decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
    private BusinessPartner businessPartner;
    private List<BusinessPartnerAddress> businessPartnerAddresses;
    private List<BusinessPartnerContact> businessPartnerContacts;
    private List<CustomerSalesArea> businessPartnerCustomerSalesArea;
    private List<CustSalesPartnerFunc> custSalesPartnerFunctions;

    CustFactSheetHandler() {

    }

    @On(event = XyzSheetContext.CDS_NAME)
    public void getCustFactSheet(GetxyzSheetContext context) {
        this.getBusinessPartner(context.getBusinessPartner());
        /*this.getBusinessPartnerAdresses();
        this.getBusinessPartnerEmail();
        this.getBusinessPartnerContacts();
        this.getBusinessPartnerCustomerSalesAreas();
        this.mapRemoteBP();*/
    }

    private void getBusinessPartner(String businessPartnerId) {
        final BusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();
        this.businessPartner = service.getBusinessPartnerByKey(businessPartnerId).executeRequest(this.httpDestination);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the specific error message, I'm having some doubts for _SAP Cloud SDK_ being at fault. Is it possible to share the code for `de.zzz.xxx.handlers.xyzHandler` and/or the required constructor arguments and/or required injectable fields for that class?

Comment: @AlexanderDümont I'm sure it is my fault ;) I added the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Semi-related answer)

I've noticed in your `xyzHandler` code, you are invoking `DestinationAccessor.getDestination(...)` on class initialization. While technically this should not be causing the problems above, I would suggest best practice:

- Move the `destination` variable declaration/initialization into your `getBusinessPartner(...)` method body. Internally *SAP Cloud SDK* is applying caching. So technically you will not notice a degradation in performance.

If we are lucky, this resolves your issue already. I think Spring Boot is applying some magic class loading here, with the handler being an application-scoped component.

Comment: That can't be true. Always this Magic. Now the service starts successfully. Whatever went wrong in the background. Best the for reference. Sometimes it needs a push :)